# making the welcome page of a website to be a servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Can I make the *welcome-file* of the website to be a servlet ? If yes , how ? I was trying something like :

```
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>FilterForwarded</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- FilterForwarded is a servlet -->
```

While deploying I do not see any error but when I try to open the website *abc.com* I get a message from the browser that it is unable to connect to this website.Why is it so ?

I want when anyone visits the website,I should be able to store the client's *public IP*. To do this I wrote a Filter which after taking the IP , passed it to the servlet (from there I could update the logs). After storing the IP , client be automatically redirected to index.jsp.  Is there any way to achieve this ?

**EDIT :**

```
    <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>FilterForwarded</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/FilterForwarded</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

This is the mapping defined in web.xml . When I use `/FilterForwarded` in welcome-file I get this message when I try to deploy : *Bad configuration: Welcome files must be relative paths: /FilterForwarded*

### **From the logs :**

```
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Welcome files must be relative paths: /FilterForwarded
at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.WebXml.validate(WebXml.java:125)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.<init>(Application.java:150)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.readApplication(Application.java:225)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:145)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:69)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:65)
```

Comment: Have you defined the `servlet-mapping` for your servlet? What is its name?

Comment: @JoãoSilva yes. It's name is /FilterForwarded.

Comment: @JoãoSilva and when I try to deploy (by keeping the same url) I get this message : Bad configuration: Welcome files must be relative paths: /FilterForwarded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you map the filter to /* you should be able to intercept all requests and then log the IP from there.

Or is your requirement to only log Client IP for the landing page?

If so, you could change the default servlet for the Servlet container, but bear in mind this will change the default servlet for *all* requests that do not match mappings in your web.xml.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FilterForwarded</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

A more complex, but potentially better solution, is to front your Java web container with a web server and use rewrite rules to proxy to your backend Servlets. This way will mean that you can control the Servlet that is accessed for your landing page without overriding the default servlet for all non-matching requests. This might be overkill for your problem though.

Comment: I get an error while deploying saying _Bad configuration: Welcome files must be relative paths: /_

Comment: after I changed the url-pattern to `/` from `/FilterForwarded`

Comment: Remove the welcome-file-list section and use the servlet mapping above instead.

Comment: yes it worked. But can you tell me why I got an error with _welcome-file-list-section_ on ?

Comment: The welcome-file section must be a partial url because it is appended to the directory url when there is no matching mapping already defined. Therefore no leading /. According to the Servlet 2.5 specification: "The Web 
server must append each welcome file in the order specified in the deployment 
descriptor to the partial request and check whether a static resource or servlet in 
the WAR is mapped to that request URI. "

Comment: There is one point I want to discuss with you @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16418/discussion-between-cuberoot-and-suhail